# The closed unit ball of a normed space $X$ is compact if and only if $X$ is finite-dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, compactness, weak-topology

This is a famous result and I would like to give it a try based on what I have learned from Brezis's *Functional Analysis*.

> Let $(X, |\cdot|)$ be a normed space and $B:= \{x \in X \mid |x|\le1\}$ the closed unit ball. Then $B$ is compact if and only if $X$ is finite-dimensional.

Could you have a check on my attempt? I'm happy to receive your comments/suggestion.

The proof relies on the following facts about weak topology $\sigma(X, X^*)$.

> **Lemma:** Let $S := \{x\in X \mid |x|=1\}$ be the unit sphere. If $X$ is infinite-dimensional, then $\overline S^{\sigma(X, X^*)} = B$. [The proof of can be found at page 59]

A direct consequence of the **Lemma** is that the unit sphere is never closed in $\sigma(X, X^*)$ if $X$ is infinite-dimensional.

- If $X$ is finite-dimensional, then $X$ is topologically isomorphic to $\mathbb R^d$ for some $d \in \mathbb N^*$. A subset of $\mathbb R^d$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. It follows that $B$ is compact.
- Let $B$ be compact in norm topology. Because $S \subset B$ is closed in norm topology, $S$ is compact in norm topology. It follows that $S$ is compact in $\sigma(X, X^*)$ which is Hausdorff. It follows that $S$ is closed $\sigma(X, X^*)$. It follows from our **Lemma** that $X$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Your statement that compact is equivalent to closed and bounded needs more precision: This is true for the standard metric, not for all metrics.

Comment: There is an elementary theorem that if $X$ is an infinite-dimensional normed vector space then the unit sphere of $X$ has an infinite subset $T$ where $\|x-y\|\ge 1/4$ for all distinct $x,y\in T.$ So $T$ is an infinite closed discrete subspace of the unit ball of $X.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DanielWainfleet has provided another approach via Riesz lemma. Below is my formulation of his idea.

---

> **Riesz lemma:** Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a normed vector space and $M$ a closed proper subspace of $E$. Let $0 < \alpha < 1$. Then there exists an $x \in E$ with $|x|=1$ such that $|x-y| \ge \alpha$ for all $y \in M$.

Any finite-dimensional subspace of $E$ is a closed proper subspace of $E$. Fix $\alpha \in (0, 1)$.

First, we pick an arbitrary $x_0 \in B$. By Riesz lemma, there is $x_1 \in B$ such that $d(x_1, \operatorname{span} \{x_0\}) \ge \alpha$. Inductively, we pick $x_{n+1} \in B$ such that
$$
d(x_{n+1}, \operatorname{span} \{x_0, \ldots, x_n\}) \ge \alpha.
$$

It follows that $(x_n) \subset B$ is not Cauchy and thus not convergent. Hence $B$ is not compact.