# If $X$ is infinite-dimensional normed vector space, then $\mathcal C_c(X) = \{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(X, |\cdot|)$ be a normed vector space. For $f:X \to \mathbb R$, the support of $f$ is defined as the closure of $\{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0\}$. Let $\mathcal C_c(X)$ be the space of all real-valued continuous functions on $X$ with compact supports.

> **Theorem** If $X$ is infinite-dimensional, then $\mathcal C_c(X) = \{0\}$.

I'm trying to prove this well-known result. Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt:** Fix $f \in \mathcal C_b(X)$. If $\{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0\} = \emptyset$ then we are done. Assume the contrary that there is $a \in X$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$. By continuity of $f$, there is an open ball $B(a, r)$ centered at $a$ with radius $r>0$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in B(a, r)$. We have $\overline{B(a, r)} \subset \operatorname{supp} f$, so $\overline{B(a, r)}$ is compact.

> [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464882/the-closed-unit-ball-of-a-normed-space-x-is-compact-if-and-only-if-x-is-fini) Let $(X, |\cdot|)$ be a normed vectpr space and $B:= \{x \in X \mid |x|\le1\}$ the closed unit ball. Then $B$ is compact if and only if $X$ is finite-dimensional.

Notice that the closed unit ball $B$ is homeomorphic to a closed subset of $\overline{B(a, r)}$, so $B$ is compact. By our **Lemma**, $X$ is finite-dimensional, which is a contradiction. This completes the proof.

Comment: (+1) Looks correct to me.